# passing a reference of an object through constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, reference

I have a class CM which has a constructor as follow:

```
CM::CM(const std::vector<Something>& vector1, const SomethingElse&     something):myVector(vector1),mySomething(something)
{
}
```

and from another class (class Ad) I want to create an object

Ad.h

```
CM* cmObj;
```

Ad.cpp

```
Ad::Ad()
{
cmObj = (CM*) malloc(1);
}
```

and I also want to instantiate my cmObj to NULL. How can I do that?

Comment: Why are you casting random memory to `CM*`?

Comment: What do you mean with "instantiate my cmObj to NULL"?? 1) `NULL` is a _null pointer constant_. 2) It is deprecated since C++11. Use `nullptr`.

Comment: `cmObj = (CM*) malloc(1);` is not correct. `cmObj = NULL;` would make it null. However there might be a better approach to whatever you're trying to do; raw pointers should generally be avoided in C++.

Comment: Why don't you use `cmObj = NULL;`..if that is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Pre C++11, use `cmdObj = NULL` to set the pointer to a null pointer value.

Don't use `malloc` and cast, as the constructor to `CM` will not be called and things like virtual function tables will not be set up correctly.

Use `cmObj = new CM(/*ToDo - constructor arguments here*/);` instead. Don't forget to call `delete cmObj;` somewhere (the *destructor* for `Ad` is a good place).

Comment: I have tried to do cmObj = new CM(null,null) but it gives an error. no matching constructor.

Comment: so if I have in the class Ad a member CM* cmObj; and I want to allocate memory for this object and to the CM constructor send another 2 members from Ad class how can I do that?